# Solve $y'=(x+y)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'=(x+y)^2$

The equation above is in the form $y'=P(x)y^2+Q(X)y+C(x)$ which is known as Ricatti equation.

I set $z=x+y$  so ${dz\over dx}={dy\over dx}+1 \implies {dy\over dx}={dz\over dx}-1 \qquad(1)  $

From the initial equation I get ${dy\over dx}=z^2  \qquad   (2)$

Finally $(1)=(2) \implies {dz\over dx}-1=z^2 \implies {1\over z^2+1}dz=dx $

If I integrate both sides with respect to x I get $atan(z)=x+c$ where c constant

Then $z=tan(x+c) \implies y=tan(x+c) -x$

**Is the logic above solid or am I mistaken somewhere?**

Comment: Whenever when you solve a DE, if you are not sure you should check your answer....

Comment: Your solution is correct. But i wonder why wolfram alpha is displaying such rubbish http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3D%28x%2By%29%5E2

Comment: I am wondering the same!

Comment: You can transform the result to the solution you obtained. I don't know why wolfram is showing this representation. But nevermind your solution work, i also checked it by plugging in the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Substitute your answer back in the original D.E.

LHS = $\sec^2(x + c) - 1$

RHS = $\tan^2(x+c)$

Is there an identity connecting the two ?

Comment: $sec^2(\theta)=1+tan^2(\theta)$ so my result is correct!

Comment: @DimitriC. Absolutely. Actually you did very well in solving. Just wonder why you did not do the reverse checking

Comment: I did but I was not sure if the identity hold truth!